# How to selectively set TX / RX speed or fake the speed of a NIC

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter

I have some kind of an odd setup where I need to set the speed of an interface so that it can receive with 1000baseT but transmit with 100baseT. TX and RX go to/come from different NICs. Is that possible at all? With ethtool you can in general set the speed, but only for the whole NIC as far as I know. My other option would be to force the speed of one of the connected NICs. However, one of those is a RPI B and trying to set the speed to 1000BaseT failed. I guess because the NIC is just 100BaseT by design. Maybe there is a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally NICs don't support independent configurations; it's also very out of spec.

This particular combination is even physically impossible as 1000baseT *doesn't have* independent Rx/Tx connections anymore – it uses all four pairs simultaneously (four bidirectional 250Mb/s lanes). So even if you managed to configure a NIC in this mode, you couldn't physically connect the 100baseT transmit pair to a different device because that'd leave you with an incomplete 1GbaseT link.

RPi original model B only has a 100 Mbps interface; you can't configure it to speak 1000 Mbps because it lacks the hardware needed.

Consider buying a Gigabit Ethernet USB adapter – it'll reach approx. 400 Mbps when connected to USB 2.0. (As far as I know, the internal RPi Ethernet is also USB-attached so there's no difference anyway...)

Comment: Or just let the hardware negotiate speeds. I suspect op dosen't realize you can run a mix of Ethernet speeds in a network